# How to stop transparent iframe overlay going over video

Tags: javascript, css, video, iframe, embedded-resource

I am placing a transaparent iframe over a page (the host page is not mine so I cannot change the code of these pages) -- some of the pages contain video.

I would still like the video to be visible and watchable.

Currently my transparent iframe layer 'blocks out the video' so you cannot watch it in Chrome.. the video *does* sit on top in Firefox.

Even in Firefox, some videos sit under, some over the layer. Does anyone know how I can make it conssitent.

Is there a way to force the iframe under the video but over the rest of the content in Chrome also?

Thank you!

Comment: I you are asking questions you should not abandon them. People are working for you so at least respond to their efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your videos are in Flash format?
If so, it depends very much on the parameters of the object/embed tag of the Flash movie.
If a wmode parameter is given and set to "opaque" or "transparent" then the Flash movie is rendered in standard z-index order into the HTML content. In this case you can place your IFrame on top of it. Without wmode the Flash movie is rendered in its own (invisible) window on top of all HTML content and you will never get your IFrame rendered over it.

Comment: Adding to this, if the video is in HTML5 format try to give the embed code a high z-index value in CSS. Simply add something like `z-index: 1000;` to the embed element and see if that fixes it.